# Create Plugins for External Site Using Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

I've just set up a Sharepoint site with a bunch of lists linked from an Access database. I also have a site (independent of Microsoft) in which I want to have forms to access and manipulate the lists on the Sharepoint site. Would it be possible to embed forms from the Sharepoint site onto the external site? If not, would I be able to make these forms on the Sharepoint site and then link to them from the external site?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you specified exactly what you meant by "embed" - are we talking of something like an iframe or you were thinking of having actual forms one the external site that access the SharePoint site via ecmascript and/or the SharePoint web services (optionally a custom one)?

Comment: Well I really can't be too specific as this is my first day working with Sharepoint and I've spent the whole day trying to figure it out (without much success unfortunately). Basically though, I am trying to make a form in Sharepoint which adds a record to one table, and then adds a variable number of records to a junction table, depending on the user's selections. I then want to have that form, still accessing the lists from the Sharepoint site, embedded in another site.